# Worksheet_Change Hide Unhide columns based on targets independently

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to hide and Unhide columns based on Yes or No in two different Targets.

My code is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Set sourceSheet = ActiveSheet
If Target.Column = 3 And Target.Row = 4 And Target.Value = "Yes" Then
    Application.Goto Reference:="Peer"
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Call sourceSheet.Activate
Else
 Application.Goto Reference:="Peer"
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Call sourceSheet.Activate
End If

If Target.Column = 5 And Target.Row = 4 And Target.Value = "Yes" Then
    Application.Goto Reference:="Apple"
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Call sourceSheet.Activate
Else
 Application.Goto Reference:="Apple"
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Call sourceSheet.Activate
End If

End Sub
```

How do I hide the columns independently from each other? If I say no for either Apples or Peers both rows get hidden and If I say Yes for Apples, the row for Peers got hidden if it was visible before.

Comment: *"How do I hide cells independently from each other?"* You can't. You can hide either rows or columns but you cannot hide individual cells. If this was not your question please clarify what your goal is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need to set `sourcesheet` as the `ActiveSheet` in this case.  You've typed *Yes* or *No* into cell `C4` or `E4` on the `Activesheet` to fire the code.

This code will hide the *Peer* or *Apple* column if you type `No`, and will unhide if you type anything else.  Add data validation to the cells to only allow *Yes* or *No*.

There's no need to select the cell to hide the column, just reference it.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address = "$C$4" Then
        Range("Peer").EntireColumn.Hidden = (Target.Value = "No")  

        'To hide column on another sheet:  
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("Peer").EntireColumn.Hidden = (Target.Value = "No")  
    ElseIf Target.Address - "$E$4" Then
        Range("Apple").EntireColumn.Hidden = (Target.Value = "No")
    End If

End Sub
```

Are you sure it's *Peer* and not *Pear*?
Do you mean the fruit, to look closely at something, or a person of the same age or social standing? :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works great! What should I add if the Range is located on a different sheet?

Comment: I've added code to show how to hide a column on a different sheet.  This uses the name shown on the sheets tab for reference, you could also use the codename `Sheet2.Range("Peer")....` which you can find on the _VBA Project Explorer_ (the sheet name not in brackets).

Answer (score 0):

You can't hide cells independently from each other as far as I know. Most that I've used for individual cells has been to write in the same color as the background (example white font on white background), but that is not hidden per say.